# Add two numbers together in asm

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have compiled the following c program to asm to see what instructions it uses. What I have in C is:

```
int add(int num1, int num2) {
    int num3 = num1 + num2;
    return num3;
}
```

My thought on what the instructions "should be" (from my very limited knowledge of asm) would be:

1. Load (two 4-byte int variables into memory).
2. Add (two memory locations), and -
3. Store the sum at a third memory location.
4. Return the value and halt execution.

When compiling this, I was surprised at all the `mov` operations it does:

```
add:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Could someone walk me through the asm code here and point out why it's using the `mov` code so frequently? Here's an example of it: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/QzyUzP).

Comment: Did you use any compiler flags like `-O3`

Comment: @Ackdari not to my knowledge, but I've used godbolt to compile it, so it might've thrown some flags in there (you can check the link above).

Comment: If you go to the box marked "Compiler options" and type in `-O3`, you see that the code generated changes to `lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]`.

Comment: Above the asm view is a text field for compiler flags if you enter `-O3` into that (i.e. all optimizations) the asm-code becones much more minimalitic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like code that was specifically compiled at the lowest possible optimization setting. What it's doing is storing the arguments (which are in the registers `edi` and `esi`) into stack memory (`rbp - offset`), then reloading them into registers `eax` and `edx` to add them, storing the result back into `int num3` in stack memory at `[rbp - 4]`, then reloading to return the result in `eax`.

A lot of this is redundant and it could just as easily be:

```
add:
    add edi, esi
    mov eax, edi
    ret
```

Or in practice with [`gcc -O1` or higher](https://godbolt.org/z/ppyhgd) is actually

```
add:
    lea    eax, [rdi+rsi]
    ret
```

The gcc/clang default is -O0 which anti-optimizes for consistent debugging, keeping variables in memory between C statements instead of registers.  See [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) for details.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. Additionally, why is the pointer offset 20 and 24, if the `int` is just 4 bytes long?

Comment: @David542  A stack frame contains multiple bits of info including the arguments passed in but also the address to return to, a pointer to the parents stack fram and some other stuff..  
 The -20 and -24 are distances from the current bottom of the stack to the function arguments.  Look here: http://stffrdhrn.github.io/software/embedded/openrisc/2018/06/08/gcc_stack_frames.html

Comment: `gcc` with `-O3` seems to be even more concise:  It just does `leal (%rdi,%rsi), %eax` followed by `ret`.